# Default Androidx (3.5) Drawer is not working in Activity

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer, androidx, android-navigation

In my project I am trying to use default Navigation drawer in Activity but it's not working, Not even hamburger icon is not being displayed.

[image]

MainActivity Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    protected DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
        setSupportActionBar( toolbar );
        drawer = findViewById( R.id.drawer_layout );
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById( R.id.nav_view );
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send, R.id.uploadActivity )
                .setDrawerLayout( drawer )
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController( this, R.id.nav_host_fragment );
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController( this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration );
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController( navigationView, navController );


        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull
                    NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
                if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_home) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "home", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_gallery) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nav_gallery", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, UploadActivity.class );
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nav_slideshow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_tools) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nav_tools", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_share) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nav_share", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (destination.getId() == R.id.uploadActivity) {
//                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nav_upload", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nav_send", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                                    Toast.makeText( UploadActivity.this, 'fsfd', Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    //                Toast.makeText( parent.getContext(), dropdown1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main, menu );
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController( this, R.id.nav_host_fragment );
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp( navController, mAppBarConfiguration )
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Implementation to Activity

```
public class UploadActivity extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_upload );
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_upload, null, false);
        drawer.addView(contentView, 0);


        Toast.makeText(this, "nav_upload", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

When I use in fragments It's working fine.
There are several methods, many packages on github but want to use it in future as it will be faster.

Comment: You can't place an `Activity` inside another. You have to use `Fragment`

Comment: If I want to use use Activity, what changes do I need to make?